# One MATRIX equation breaking into two row as per format, but I want only one equation number instead of two

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, matrices

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{a}\\
\dot{b}\\
\dot{c}\\
\dot{d}\\
\dot{e}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.3935 & 0.3331 & -2.5632 & -9.7736 &0\\
-0.4334 & -1.7234 & 34.9060 & -0.7177 &0\\
0.0568 & -0.7741 & -10.6468 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0.0732 & -0.9973 & 0 & 34.9999 &0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e
\end{bmatrix}\\
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4505 & 30.6976\\
6.1355 & 0\\
-35.7476 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{f}\\
\delta_{g}
\end{bmatrix}\label{eq:13}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: either  use `\nonumber` on one of the lines, or use `multine` rather than `gather` or use `equation` then split with `gathered` inside the numbered equation

Comment: unrelated but it's best to avoid numbers in labels like `eq:13`

Answer (score 5):

Three possibilities, I think `multline` is possibly the most semantically correct here, it is a single equation, split over thelines, but use whichever layout you like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


gather
\begin{gather}\nonumber
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{a}\\
\dot{b}\\
\dot{c}\\
\dot{d}\\
\dot{e}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.3935 & 0.3331 & -2.5632 & -9.7736 &0\\
-0.4334 & -1.7234 & 34.9060 & -0.7177 &0\\
0.0568 & -0.7741 & -10.6468 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0.0732 & -0.9973 & 0 & 34.9999 &0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e
\end{bmatrix}\\
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4505 & 30.6976\\
6.1355 & 0\\
-35.7476 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{f}\\
\delta_{g}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}

multline
\begin{multline}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{a}\\
\dot{b}\\
\dot{c}\\
\dot{d}\\
\dot{e}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.3935 & 0.3331 & -2.5632 & -9.7736 &0\\
-0.4334 & -1.7234 & 34.9060 & -0.7177 &0\\
0.0568 & -0.7741 & -10.6468 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0.0732 & -0.9973 & 0 & 34.9999 &0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e
\end{bmatrix}\\
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4505 & 30.6976\\
6.1355 & 0\\
-35.7476 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{f}\\
\delta_{g}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{multline}

gathered
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{a}\\
\dot{b}\\
\dot{c}\\
\dot{d}\\
\dot{e}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.3935 & 0.3331 & -2.5632 & -9.7736 &0\\
-0.4334 & -1.7234 & 34.9060 & -0.7177 &0\\
0.0568 & -0.7741 & -10.6468 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0.0732 & -0.9973 & 0 & 34.9999 &0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e
\end{bmatrix}\\
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4505 & 30.6976\\
6.1355 & 0\\
-35.7476 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{f}\\
\delta_{g}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution option that generates a single, vertically centered equation number: a combination of `equation` and `split` (or `aligned`) environments.

I would also like to suggest that you align the numbers in the two matrices on their respective decimal points in order to make them easier to eyeball and (hopefully) study carefully. This may be achieved by using `array` environments and the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' environment
\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:13}
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{a}\\ \dot{b}\\ \dot{c}\\ \dot{d}\\ \dot{e}
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\left[\begin{array}{@{} *{2}{T{-1.4}} T{-2.4} T{-1.4} c @{}}
-0.3935 & 0.3331 & -2.5632 & -9.7736 &0\\
-0.4334 & -1.7234 & 34.9060 & -0.7177 &0\\
0.0568 & -0.7741 & -10.6468 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0.0732 & -0.9973 & 0 & 34.9999 &0
\end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ b\\ c\\ d\\ e
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\quad+
\left[\begin{array}{@{} T{-2.4} T{2.4} @{}}
-0.4505 & 30.6976\\
6.1355 & 0\\
-35.7476 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_{f}\\[1ex] \delta_{g}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```